# Sequential Increase in Column value based on a condition R

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, data-transform, sequential-number

I have an R data frame that has an ID column with multiple records for an ID. When the flag is set to 1 for an ID, I want to create a column new timeline that starts from 1 and increases sequentially in increments of 6 (1,6,12...). How can I achieve this in R using dplyr ?

Below is a sample data frame

| ID | Timepoint | Flag |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 |
| A | 6 | 0 |
| A | 12 | 0 |
| A | 18 | 1 |
| A | 24 | 0 |
| A | 30 | 0 |
| A | 36 | 0 |

Expected Dataframe

| ID | Timepoint | Flag | New_Timepoint |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 0 | 0 |  |
| A | 6 | 0 |  |
| A | 12 | 0 |  |
| A | 18 | 1 | 1 |
| A | 24 | 0 | 6 |
| A | 30 | 0 | 12 |
| A | 36 | 0 | 18 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another `dplyr` option

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(New_Timepoint = pmax(1, Timepoint - c(NA, Timepoint[Flag == 1])[cumsum(Flag) + 1])) %>%
  ungroup()
```

gives

```
  ID    Timepoint  Flag New_Timepoint
  <chr>     <int> <int>         <dbl>
1 A             0     0            NA
2 A             6     0            NA
3 A            12     0            NA
4 A            18     1             1
5 A            24     0             6
6 A            30     0            12
7 A            36     0            18
```

Answer (score 2):

An option is to group by 'ID', create the `lag` of the 'Timepoint' with `n` specified as the position of 'Flag' where the value is 1 (-1)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(New_Timepoint = dplyr::lag(replace(Timepoint, !Timepoint, 1),
           n = which(Flag == 1)-1)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
#  ID    Timepoint  Flag New_Timepoint
#  <chr>     <int> <int>         <dbl>
#1 A             0     0            NA
#2 A             6     0            NA
#3 A            12     0            NA
#4 A            18     1             1
#5 A            24     0             6
#6 A            30     0            12
#7 A            36     0            18
```

---

Or use a double `cumsum` to create the index

```
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(New_Timepoint = Timepoint[na_if(cumsum(cumsum(Flag)), 0)]) %>%
   ungroup
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"), 
    Timepoint = c(0L, 
6L, 12L, 18L, 24L, 30L, 36L), 
     Flag = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```